# Limited joining of a huge table to itself in Oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, bigdata

The problem:  We are wanting to remove misspelled addresses from our database.  But we have too many to do by hand.  So instead, I have a function, FN, that returns true if two addresses appear very similar (indicating a possible misspelling).  A simple check would be to do something like...

```
select *
from
    address adr1
    join address adr2
    on FN(adr1, adr2)
```

But, this basically does a cross join and compares rows.  This is impossible to do due to how large our table is (> 1 million rows).  But, I can limit it to looking at only addresses near each other.  For example, addresses within the same city.  So, I tried doing a count of addresses like that by doing...

```
select count(1)
from
    address adr1
    join address adr2
    on adr1.zip = adr2.zip
    and adr1.city = adr2.city
    --Don't want to compare to self
    and adr1.ID <> adr2.ID
```

The problem is that this takes too long to run (I've waited and it still hasn't finished).  I suspect that oracle has a much better way to handle doing these type of things for large numbers of rows, but I just don't know it.

So how should a person go about joining an extreme large table to itself if there are ways to limit what is being joined (such as only looking within the same zipcode)?

P.S.  Do trillions of records count as big data or should I remove the tag?

Edit1:  Zip and City are already indexed.

Edit2:  Zip and City both have large numbers of null values 200,000+.  This may affect how the index is used in the join.

Explain plan:

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 35,301  Bytes: 42  Cardinality: 1           
    4 SORT AGGREGATE  Bytes: 42  Cardinality: 1         
        3 HASH JOIN  Cost: 35,301  Bytes: 2,195,769,492  Cardinality: 52,280,226    
            1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE SCHEMA.ADDRESS Cost: 15,677  Bytes: 21,388,962  Cardinality: 1,018,522  
            2 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE SCHEMA.ADDRESS Cost: 15,677  Bytes: 21,388,962  Cardinality: 1,018,522
```

Edit3:  I've tried counting the number of rows I'll be looking at a different way.

```
select
    sum(cnt * (cnt - 1))
from
(
select
    count(1) as CNT
from schema.address adr1
group by adr1.zip, adr1.city
)
```

This returned ~45 billion different pairings in less than 10 seconds.  I'm not sure my function can handle more than 100k rows a second, which is what would be needed to have this run in under 12 hours.

Comment: How complicated is your `FN`?

Comment: Your second query looks OK.  Oracle has ways to handle joining large amounts of data, for example with a hash join.  And 1 million rows isn't even really a large amount of data.  If you post the explain plan someone may be able to help you tune the query.

Comment: @Gerrat  I'd say pretty nasty as it is doing all sort of string operations and involving context switches.  That being said, does that matter much for trying to optimize the join?

Comment: The only reason I asked is that if it wasn't too complicated, there might be better ways of doing this than using the function & the join in the first place.  Doesn't appear like that's possible though.

Comment: I was just going to mention (before your latest edit), that even if you could solve the join issue, I bet your function will take too long.  You mention 100000/second...if it's doing context switches, it may only do 1000 comparisons/second.  I think you may want to try another approach - maybe export your data, group it by something like a soundex, and go from there.

Comment: @Lawtonfogle: Your function *may* include some criteria that can be used to further restrict the number of rows that need to be joined to each other - including these additional criteria in the query would not *strictly* be optimising the *existing* query, but *could* lead to a faster query. Also, can you try running your row-counting query with the additional clause: `where adr1.zip is not null and adr1.city is not null` ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Build an index on fields `ZIP` and `CITY`

2) To get duplicates (this is what you do in second case) use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ZIP,CITY, count(*) FROM ADDRESS HAVING COUNT(*)>1 GROUP BY ZIP,CITY
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got some good news, and some bad news.

The good news is that your existing query is likely to have closer to 5 billion rows, than 45 billion rows.

The bad news is that this is because it won't try to match up any of the 200,000 records that have null zip or null city values - Oracle (and all other RDBMSs I know) won't join NULL values to other NULL values; see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93ae0/1) for an example. You can get round this using a `coalesce` as part of the join criteria, but I suggest handling null city/zip records separately instead.

Assuming that your function handles addresses symmetrically (so that `FN(addr1,addr2)` returns the same result as `FN(addr2,addr1)`), you can further halve the number of combinations by changing `adr1.ID <> adr2.ID` to `adr1.ID < adr2.ID` in your existing query. If you don't already have a suitable index, I suggest adding one on zip, city and id (in that order).

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to encode each address with postal authority idcode, if that exists for the addresses/country in question. This means that rather than comparing each address to itself, you put all the effort into parsing and decoding the address in the first place. We use this approach, and store the id in each row, which means we can join later very precisely and quickly.

If you cannot use postal id (and by this I mean unique id's for each delivery address assigned by the post office), then consider geo coding each address and then joining by geo near addressses. Geo coding might also apply if the addresses arent purely postal addresses.

I'm also quite interested in what FN() does for the addresses, have you seen http://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/ not related to your question, but good reading if you are new to address handling.